# Insert a blank row between each grouping in a dataframe BUT only display the first header

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The following code courtesy of @jezrael displays a blank row AND a Header for each grouping

```
data = {
            'MARKET_SECTOR_DES':['A','A','B','B','B','B'],
            'count':[10,9,20,19,18,17]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print("")

# retrieve column headers
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[''] * len(df.columns), df.columns], columns=df.columns)
# For each grouping Apply insert headers
df1 = (df.groupby('MARKET_SECTOR_DES', group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda d: d.append(df2))
        .iloc[:-2]
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   MARKET_SECTOR_DES  count
0                  A     10
1                  A      9
2                          
3  MARKET_SECTOR_DES  count
4                  B     20
5                  B     19
6                  B     18
7                  B     17
```

Desired output:

```
   MARKET_SECTOR_DES  count
0                  A     10
1                  A      9                     

4                  B     20
5                  B     19
6                  B     18
7                  B     17
```

So only the single header at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `df2` to

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[''] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns)
```